# Select an option in a javascript drop down menu with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

To select "Closed" from this drop-down menu with a macro :

```html
<div class="modal ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="pausingModal" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: auto;">
<label>Please specify the reason</label>
<div class="row">
<div class="select2-container select2 reason select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open" id="s2id_autogen2" style="width: 100%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">Select a reason</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3" disabled=""></div><select class="select2 reason select2-offscreen" style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1" title="">
<option></option>
<optgroup label="Related">
<option data-pause-type="hard_pause" data-show-text-area="false" value="1">
Closed
</option>
```

I tried different solutions, tried to retrieve all option names then select the innertext but the option does not get selected in the menu :

```
For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("select2 reason").getElementsByTagName("option")
If obj.innerText = "Closed" Then
obj.Selected = True
End If
Next

For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("select2 reason").getElementsByTagName("option")
If obj.Value = "1" Then
obj.Selected = True
End If
Next
```

I tried with an onchange event:

```
Dim o
For Each o In objIE.Options
    If o.Value = "1" Then
        o.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Dim objEvent
Set objEvent = objIE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
objIE.dispatchEvent objEvent
```

EDIT : it turns out there was javascript in the code, therefore I modified as followed :

```
For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If obj.id = "select2-chosen-3" Then
obj.Focus
obj.innerText = "Business Closed Permanently"
Exit For
End If
Next
```

It populates the menu but when I click it is like nothing was selected.

I tried then to add :

```
For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
If obj.className = "select2-choice select2-default" Then
obj.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Why are you using VBA instead of JS?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am writing a macro to access this website and automatize a team task. Are you saying that this is too complex to do with VBA ?

Comment: You might try setting the value of the select itself

Comment: automatize? Is this some nuance on automate?

Comment: You can try the below syntax  `objIE.Document..getElementById("pausingModal").selectedIndex = 1`                                                       
`objIE.Document..getElementById("pausingModal").FireEvent ("onchange")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried it but still no luck, nothing gets selected.

Comment: I edited my post with the solution you suggested.

Comment: Is this an internal URL? Can you collect all the option tags loop until text "Closed" found then .Click ?

Comment: Yes it is an internal URL. I tried it but nothing get selected.     For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If obj.innerText = " Closed" Then
    obj.Click

Comment: Would that help if I put more of the HTML code ?

Comment: Is the Closed present in the innerText i.e. when you loop is it found?

Comment: Yes it is found. With a getElementsByTagName("option") with innertext="Closed", I can put it down in a sheet. But unable to click.

Comment: Are there any events associated you could fire or jscript you can execute? I can't see any in the above but thought I'd mention.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the HTML code, there was a javascript element. I edited my post. Then now I wrote :     `For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If obj.id = "select2-chosen-3" Then
    obj.Focus
    obj.innerText = "Closed"`
It populates my menu at last ! But then when the code clicks on OK it is like nothing was selected. Would you have any idea ?